# Visit button not displaying different dates and times

Tags: java, date, time

In my program, I have a visit button that allows a user to view how many times an engineer has logged into the server. The button should display the different dates and times that the engineer has logged in. However it displays the same date and time as the first time the engineer logged into the server. Any assistance would be helpful.

Code:

```
public String visits(String myCookie){
        if(numberOfVisits == 0){
            return "Engineer has not visited this machine";
        }else if(myCookie.equals(storedCookie)){
            for(int i = 0; i < numberOfVisits; i++){
            System.out.println("Engineer has visited on these dates: " + dateFormat.format(storedDate));
            }
            return storedCookie;
        }else{
            for(int i = 0; i < numberOfVisits; i++){
                System.out.println("Engineer has visited on these date: " + dateFormat.format(storedDate));
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should only post the relevant parts of your code pertaining to the question. People aren't going to want to sift through your entire program to try and find the part you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic must be coherent with what you get as parameter I would suggest change the order of what you check, so your branches will be clearer and easier to execute:

```
public String visits(String myCookie){
        if(myCookie.equals(storedCookie)){
             if(numberOfVisits == 0)
                  return "Engineer has not visited this machine";
             for(int i = 0; i < numberOfVisits; i++){
                 System.out.println("Engineer has visited on these dates: " + dateFormat.format(storedDate));
             }
             return storedCookie;
        }
    return "";
    }
```

I dont know this storedDate variable
but this here :
System.out.println("Engineer has visited on these dates: " + dateFormat.format(storedDate));
is going to print the same date...

you should have that in some array and get it with the index

```
System.out.println("Engineer has visited on these dates: " + dateFormat.format(storedDate[i]));
```

Comment: This solution did not work as I can no longer print the visits when the user is logged out and it still displays the same date as when the user first logged in.

`Engineer has visited on these dates: 29/04/2016 19:55
Engineer has visited on these dates: 29/04/2016 19:55
Engineer has visited on these dates: 29/04/2016 19:55`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.

You seem to asking to collect the dates on which a person has logged in. So you need to keep a collection object for each user. Not sure if you want date-only or date-time; I'll go with date-time.

We will use a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) to keep them in chronological order as they happen.

We will use the [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class, a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds. Part of the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later.

```
List<Instant> logins = new ArrayList<>();
```

When that user logs in, add the current moment.

```
logins.add( Instant.now() );
```

When you want to display those collected values, just loop. The `toString` method generates a String in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format by default.

```
System.out.println( "You logged in at these date-times:" );
for( Instant instant:logins ) {
    String output = instant.toString();
    System.out.println( output );
}
```

You can apply a [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) to adjust into the [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_clock_time) expected by the user.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
```

To use another format, see the [java.time.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/package-summary.html) package. You can even let java.time automatically localize the output for you. Specify a `Locale` for human language to translate name of day/month and for the cultural norms of period-versus-comma and so on.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.MEDIUM );
formatter = formatter.withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );
```

Use that formatter in your loop.

```
    String output = zdt.format( formatter );
```

If you have more to your Question, then you should edit and rewrite.